# Error while inserting data into database in line 27

Tags: php, database

So I'm trying to create a simple sign up the program that inserts the data into a MySQL database:

```
<?php


$first=$_POST['name'];
$last=$_POST['lname'];
$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

if(empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($uname) || empty($pass))
{
    header('Location: redirect.php');
}
else
{
    $conn=new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "login");

    if($conn->connect_error)
    {
        die("We've lost the connection because of ".$conn->connect_error);
    }

    $insert="INSERT INTO people (name, lastname, username, pass) VALUES ('$name', '$last', '$uname', '$pass')";
    $conn->query($insert);
}

?>
```

However when i run the program and insert the data I get the error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtor\sign_up.php on line 27

line 27 is this line:

```
$insert="INSERT INTO people (name, lastname, username, pass) VALUES 
('$name', '$last', '$uname', '$pass')";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error was clear; why did you not Google that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$name should be called $first as set at the top of the script. Change

`VALUES ('$name', '$last',`

to

`VALUES ('$first', '$last',`

Comment: Oh my god how did I not see that! Thanks very much it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You do not define a variable called name, but only a variable called first